# PDO Insert throws an unexplained "Array to string conversion" error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've got the following function

```
public function addProduct($type, $title, $url
        , $small_image_id, $large_image_id, $number, $number_type
        , $formatted_number, $fk) {

    switch (strtoupper($type)) {
        case 'FOO':
            $ind = 1;
            break;
        case 'BARR':
            $ind = 2;
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }

    $sql=   "INSERT INTO product(fk_id, type_id, title, url, ".
                                        "sm_image_id, lg_image_id, number, ".
                                        "num_type, num_formatted)".
            "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    return $this->insertIdAfterInsert($sql,'iissiiiss',array($fk
            , $ind, $title , $url, $small_image_id
            , $large_image_id, $number, $number_type, $formatted_number));
}
```

Where insertIdAfterInsert() is:

```
private function insertIdAfterInsert($sql,$types = null,$params = null) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->conn->errno . ' ' . $this->conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if($types&&$params)
    {
        $typeArr = str_split($types);
        for($i=0; $i< count($params); $i++) {
            if ($typeArr[$i] === 'i') {
                $bind_type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            } elseif($typeArr[$i]==='s'){
                $bind_type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
            $stmt->bindValue($i+1, $params[$i], $bind_type);
        }
    }

echo (var_dump($stmt->debugDumpParams()));

    try {
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->conn->errorCode() . ' ' . $this->conn->errorInfo(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->conn->errorCode() . ' ' . $this->conn->errorInfo(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stmt = null;
    return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

**UPDATE:** The catch() is where the error prints

I'm passing in

```
addProduct('Foo', 'Cohort', 'http://www.gooo...', 0, 0, 0, ' ', ' ', 210)
```

My error shows that insertIdAfterInsert is getting

```
insertIdAfterInsert('INSERT INTO aff...', 'iissiiiss', Array)
```

and the debugDumpParams looks like this:

```
SQL: [183] INSERT INTO affiliate_product(fk_id, type_id, title, url, sm_image_id, lg_image_id, number, num_type, num_formatted)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Params:  9
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #3:
paramno=3
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #4:
paramno=4
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #5:
paramno=5
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #6:
paramno=6
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Position #7:
paramno=7
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #8:
paramno=8
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
NULL
```

(i'm not sure about that last NULL, but echoed a functioning insert and the same NULL appears so i'm not too worried about it)

Can anyone tell me why this would be throwing the "Array to string conversion"??

Thanks

Comment: Does the error mention a line number?

Comment: Doesn't [`PDO::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.errorinfo.php) return an array? You're concatenating it in your `trigger_error` calls

Comment: Interestingly no, I don't actually see the Trigger_error() message in my output - let me see if I can get that back

Comment: MUTHER!  that was it! it was my dat-gum error message!  THE WHOLE TIME!

var_dump(errorInfo()) gave
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil!

The error was I-D-10-T and was due to improperly handling the array that PDO::errorInfo() outputs.  Still not sure what the error is with my query but I'm off to the Google machine and more echoes to find my answer.

THANKS PHIL!

All though sloppy I altered my trigger_error() to the following:

```
trigger_error('Error: ' . $this->conn->errorCode() . ' ' . var_dump($this->conn->errorInfo()), E_USER_ERROR);
```

My error was not with PDO